# DatagramPacket is accumulating values

Tags: java, runnable, datagram

I created a chat in Java, which displays the messages sent and received on the screen. The problem is that when sending the message it is picking up the previously sent value. For example, I send the message written "Microsoft", and then I send another message written "Apple", when the display shows "Applesoft", it appears that it is not emptying DatagramPacket. What can be done?

```
    class Recebe implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] dadosReceber = new byte[255];
            boolean erro = false;
            DatagramSocket socket = null;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    socket = new DatagramSocket(getPorta());
                } catch (SocketException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                erro = false;
                while (!erro) {
                    DatagramPacket pacoteRecebido = new DatagramPacket(dadosReceber, dadosReceber.length);
                    try {
                        socket.receive(pacoteRecebido);
                        byte[] b = pacoteRecebido.getData();
                        String s = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                            if (b[i] != 0) {
                                s += (char) b[i];
                                System.out.println("Valor S: " + s + " ");
                            }
                        }

//                        if (!s.equals(new GeraHash().MD5("envie a chave publica!!!"))) {
                            String nome = pacoteRecebido.getAddress().toString() + " disse:";
                            notifica(nome + s);
                            System.out.println("Dados Recebe 2: " + s + " ");
//                        } else {
//                            conexaoAtual().envia("Funcionou!");
//                            System.out.println("Dados Recebe 1: " + s + " ");
//                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("erro");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        erro = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.receive(pacoteRecebido);
byte[] b = pacoteRecebido.getData();
String s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
if (b[i] != 0) {
    s += (char) b[i];
    System.out.println("Valor S: " + s + " ");
}
```

Usual problem. You're ignoring the actual length of the received datagram, given by `DatagramPacket.getLength()`. You can reduce all that to:

```
socket.receive(pacoteRecebido);
System.out.println(new String(pacoteRecebido.getData(), 0, pacoteRecebido.getLength());
```